# Problema con react y firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

estoy teniendo un problema con React y Firebase, sucede que cuando instale todo, importe el SDK a un archivo llamado firebaseconfig.js, que esta ubicado en la carpeta src de firebase.

```
 import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/auth' 

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x-x.x.com",
  projectId: "x-x",
  storageBucket: "x-x.x.x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x:x:x:x",
  measurementId: "x-x"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = app.auth(); //Lo inicializamos para poder usarlo en el resto de la aplicación

export {auth}; // Exportamos el objeto auth para poder usarlo en el resto de la aplicación
```

y luego lo importe en mi componenete donde quiero utilizar el auth de firebase

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react'
import '../css/login.css'

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

pero el problema que me sale al recargar la pagina es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro por ningun lado como poder solucionar esto,  tengo firebase instalado:

```
   {
  "name": "veterinaria",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "firebase": "^9.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

Agradezco toda su ayuda

Comment: Por favor agrega el código cómo texto y no como imagen. Te recomiendo leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Listo @AndresGardiol

Comment: Elimina el segundo import y prueba. Firebase/auth no hace falta importarlo tal como lo has inicializado. A menos que quieras inicializarlo con la versión 9 de la documentación